# Wordpress Plugin: Nested and Pagination

Tags: pagination, wordpress, threaded-comments

I have a blog that gets a number of comments each day. I am looking for a plugin which supports nested comments as well as pagination - the default supplied by wordpress just says "Newer Comments" and "Older Comments" which is not SEO friendly. Ideally, the pagination should display "all page numbers" (example; 1, 2, 3, 4, See ALl) - so there are links to all paginated pages from all pages - Good for seo.

Anyone know about this? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programmer Q&A site. If you do not need help writing your own code, you're in the wrong place. Try the WordPress StackExchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, or the official WordPress site and its forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [wordpress thread comment](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-thread-comment/) plugin on my pages, and I'm very satisfied with it. 
you can also stylize it with CSS to your liking.